# How to prepend a prefix to a python string when the string is stored as a variable?

Tags: python, string

I have string literal, let's say 'test string'. I can simply do `r'test string'` to prepend the prefix.

However, now I have `s = 'test string'`. How do I prepend the PREFIX `r` (not the string 'r') to this string in this case ?

Here is my json-embedded string (it's crawled using twitter API I believed):

```
{"created_at":"Fri Mar 21 15:27:05 +0000 2014","id":447031650824646656,"id_str":"447031650824646656","text":"\u4eca\u65e5\u304a\u7948\u308a\u3057\u3066\u304d\u305f\u304b\u3089\u306d http:\/\/t.co\/EVgVEOyF2Q","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1615583810,"id_str":"1615583810","name":"\u30c8\u30e1\u6ca2","screen_name":"tome_sawa","location":"\u8c6a\u5dde","url":"http:\/\/riceriot.tumblr.com\/","description":"SNK\uff08\u5208\u308a\u4e0a\u3052\u30b5\u30f3\u30c9\uff09\/APH\uff08\u672c\u7530\u69d8 \u5cf6\u56fd \u4e00\u4eba\u307c\u3063\u3061\u540c\u76df\uff09\/\u8150\/\u6d77\u5916\u30cd\u30bf\/\u6210\u4eba\u6e08\/\u81ea\u7531\u3067\u3059\/ \u6210\u4eba\u63a8\u5968 \/pixiv id=2452371\/ http:\/\/ask.fm\/tomesawa","protected":false,"followers_count":323,"friends_count":93,"listed_count":15,"created_at":"Tue Jul 23 16:04:57 +0000 2013","favourites_count":835,"utc_offset":32400,"time_zone":"Irkutsk","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":9199,"lang":"ja","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000120467721\/5ba3a7a1a51c27d5846a21497ed626e3.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000120467721\/5ba3a7a1a51c27d5846a21497ed626e3.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/435018392261513216\/rDsSbqDS_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/435018392261513216\/rDsSbqDS_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1615583810\/1375715189","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"media":[{"id":447031650489081856,"id_str":"447031650489081856","indices":[13,35],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/BjQs6urCIAAl3Gk.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/BjQs6urCIAAl3Gk.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/EVgVEOyF2Q","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/EVgVEOyF2Q","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/tome_sawa\/status\/447031650824646656\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":600,"h":600,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":1024,"h":1024,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":340,"h":340,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":true,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"ja"}
```

I tried the following code:

```
s = '{"created_at":"Fri Mar 21 15:27:05 +0000 2014","id":447031650824646656,"id_str":"447031650824646656","text":"\u4eca\u65e5\u304a\u7948\u308a\u3057\u3066\u304d\u305f\u304b\u3089\u306d http:\/\/t.co\/EVgVEOyF2Q","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1615583810,"id_str":"1615583810","name":"\u30c8\u30e1\u6ca2","screen_name":"tome_sawa","location":"\u8c6a\u5dde","url":"http:\/\/riceriot.tumblr.com\/","description":"SNK\uff08\u5208\u308a\u4e0a\u3052\u30b5\u30f3\u30c9\uff09\/APH\uff08\u672c\u7530\u69d8 \u5cf6\u56fd \u4e00\u4eba\u307c\u3063\u3061\u540c\u76df\uff09\/\u8150\/\u6d77\u5916\u30cd\u30bf\/\u6210\u4eba\u6e08\/\u81ea\u7531\u3067\u3059\/ \u6210\u4eba\u63a8\u5968 \/pixiv id=2452371\/ http:\/\/ask.fm\/tomesawa","protected":false,"followers_count":323,"friends_count":93,"listed_count":15,"created_at":"Tue Jul 23 16:04:57 +0000 2013","favourites_count":835,"utc_offset":32400,"time_zone":"Irkutsk","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":9199,"lang":"ja","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000120467721\/5ba3a7a1a51c27d5846a21497ed626e3.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000120467721\/5ba3a7a1a51c27d5846a21497ed626e3.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/435018392261513216\/rDsSbqDS_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/435018392261513216\/rDsSbqDS_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1615583810\/1375715189","profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"media":[{"id":447031650489081856,"id_str":"447031650489081856","indices":[13,35],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/BjQs6urCIAAl3Gk.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/BjQs6urCIAAl3Gk.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/EVgVEOyF2Q","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/EVgVEOyF2Q","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/tome_sawa\/status\/447031650824646656\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"medium":{"w":600,"h":600,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":1024,"h":1024,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"small":{"w":340,"h":340,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":true,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"ja"}'
json.loads(s);
```

it gives me this error:

```
----> 1 json.loads(s)
.................
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 234 (char 233)
```

My python version is 2.7.7.

Comment: Sorry, I mean prepend a prefix, not a string to a string

Comment: If your 'code is crashing', post the error. The question as-is is very vague

Comment: But when I tried r'the string' above, it works

Comment: Post your code, not pseudo code

Comment: That is all my code.
s = the string above;
json.loads(s);

Comment: Done! sorry for that

Comment: Don't post a picture.  Do you expect us to type it in manually to try it, or to count in the picture to character 234 to see what character is causing the issue???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so your problem seems to be that your input string is not valid JSON.  Here is an excerpt I cut out from the input you added to your question:

```
{"source":"\\u003ca href="http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/iphone"
  rel="nofollow"\\u003eTwitter for iPhone\\u003c\\/a\\u003e"}
```

If I decode the unicode characters, it looks like this:

```
{"source":"<a href="http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/iphone""}
```

The main problem I see is with the quotes: you have a quoted string inside another quoted string, and they both use the same quote character.  This simply cannot work.

If you write it this way, it will work:

```
{"source":"<a href=\'http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/iphone\'"}
```

But maybe you need double quotes.  It's not really clear how you're getting this data in the first place--perhaps you have access to a more "raw" version of the input which doesn't have these problems.  But once you're here, you can't fix it by simply "prepending `r`", because that's something that only makes sense when you have a literal string.

Comment: Got it!!!!!! Thanks a lot. Actually just solved it with other method, i.e. the one you mention, not dealing with this string directly...